# Why do i get the message "Requests throttled" when the App-Servicename contains "ß"

Tags: azure, naming, azure-web-app-service

I've got here a little question about the naming for an App-Service.
Today I created a new App-Service for one Service an the name i used was like "DummyNameß". So, now here is my question/problem?
If the name of an App-Service contains the letter "ß" it gives me the "Requests throttled" Error if I want to add a new WebJob.

Does anybody know why this happens?
Is this a technical error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, avoid having any special characters (`-` or `_`) as the first or **last** character in any name. These characters will cause most validation rules to fail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#naming-rules-and-restrictions